# python possible to debug without modifying code

Tags: python, debugging, command-line

It seems that debugging python code is a trivial task, just insert the following lines to trigger the debugger.

```
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
```

Yeah, so I tried that, and it works really well. It's a decent debugger.

But is it possible to launch an unmodified python program, perhaps specifying a text file, listing breakpoint locations? That's how I usually do it in Java or Flash.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use an IDE?  Eclipse+PyDev provides some pretty useful tools for developing and debugging.  The runtime expression engine combined with breakpoints has saved me countless hours alone.

Comment: gui option - [winpdb](http://winpdb.org/about/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Save a file called `.pdbrc` in the same folder as your script file. Put in it your breakpoint information:

```
b 3
b 5
b 70
b 89
```

Run your script in pdb like so:

```
python -m pdb myscript.py
```

and pdb will pick up and insert your breakpoints. Unfortunetly it won't save any changes you make to them while debugging.

Alternatively you can specify them on the first line

```
(Pdb) b 3;;b 5;;b 70;;b 89
```

Answer (score 6):

As explained in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html), you can run it with:

```
python -m pdb myscript.py
```

Answer (score 2):

If using pytest, `pytest --trace` will stop at the first testcase.